# How do you access the value for input or select outside of form tags

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to use a select element that is located outside of the form tags. HTML5 allows `<select form="myform" name="myselect">`

All the following examples work if I move the select in between the form tags, but that would defeat the purpose of the 'form=' attribute.

I also do not want to use an id= in the select field as I will have multiple forms on the same page.

Thanks.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
  alert("1: " + $('#myform select[name="myselect"]').val());
  
  myform = $('#myform');
  alert("2: " + myform.find('select[name="myselect"]').val());  

  alert("3: " + $('#myform select').val());
  
  myform = $('#myform');
  alert("4: " + myform.find('select').val());

  // works
  alert("5: " + $('select[form="myform"][name="myselect"]').val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <form id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="myhidden" value="2" />
    <input id="mybutton" type="button" name="Go" value="Go" />
 
  </form>
   
  <select form="myform" name="myselect">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>  
</div>
```

Comment: Number 5 works, so what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @alexP and TiiJ7 - maybe that's all that is necessary. My intent was to find the form, then find the select/input belonging to this form. The case is that if I have say 50 forms (with unique ids) and the inputs/selects were identical, I can then pass the form object and efficiently search for the select.

If I use $('select[name="myselect"]').val()), then the backend is probably iterating through all select elements on that page. 

Some more thought and if I mix and match javascript with jquery, this works too: document.getElementById("myform").elements["myselect"].value

Answer (score 0):

You can't select your Dropdown with:

```
$('#myform select[name="myselect"]').val();
```

because there is no child element with the name `myselect` in the element with the ID `myform` in DOM.

You'll have to use

```
$('select[name="myselect"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` :

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
  
  $( ".sel" ).each(function ( index ) {
     alert( index + " number of select box value : " + $( this ).val() );
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <form id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="myhidden" value="2" />
    <input id="mybutton" type="button" name="Go" value="Go" />
 
  </form>
   
  <select class="sel" form="myform" name="myselect">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>  
</div>
```

Now you can have multiple selections with the same class and iterate them.